# Prove $\tan (A-B)=\dfrac{2\sin B}{1-2 \cos B}$ , if $2\sin A = \sin (A-B)$

Tags: trigonometry

If $2\sin A = \sin (A-B)$,

Prove that ,  $\tan (A-B)=\dfrac{2\sin B}{1-2 \cos B}$.

Thanks for helping, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
2\sin(A)=\sin(A)\cos(B)-\cos(A)\sin(B)
&\implies\sin(A)(\cos(B)-2)=\cos(A)\sin(B)
\end{align}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(A-B)
&=\frac{\sin(A-B)}{\cos(A-B)}\\
&=\frac{2\sin(A)}{\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)}\\
&=\frac{2\sin(A)}{\sin(A)(\cos(B)-2)\cot(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{2}{(\cos(B)-2)\cot(B)+\sin(B)}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{2\sin(B)}{(\cos(B)-2)\cos(B)+\sin^2(B)}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{2\sin(B)}{1-2\cos(B)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

As we need to eliminate $A$ keeping $A-B,B$

we can write $\sin(A)=\sin(\underbrace{A-B}+B)$

Using $\sin(C-D)=\sin C\cos D-\cos C\sin D,$

$$\sin(A-B)=2\sin A=2[\sin(A-B)\cos B+\cos(A-B)\sin B]$$

$$\iff\sin(A-B)[1-2\cos B]=\cos(A-B)[2\sin B]$$

Are we done?

Comment: your idea is smart but the previous one seems to be more complete, I should have checked the tick earlier! Thank you for answering :$

Comment: @伍柒貳 , Never mind. I'd have produced this even if you'd accepted the other as it's different & smarter